# Superman story where he makes Jimmy Olsen forget his secret ID

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

As a follow-up to a comment I posted on another question, I'm trying to identify a Superman story where Jimmy Olsen accidentally discovered his secret identity. As Jimmy was worried that he might be tortured into revealing the information in the future, Superman made him forget it by burning out that specific portion of his brain with a combination of heat and microscopic visions, possibly focussed through some kind of jewel. To prevent this being used as a get-out in later stories, Superman specifically said that he could never do it again without short-circuiting his vision powers. I think the story appeared in the late 1970s or possibly early '80s - certainly pre-Crisis.

Comment: What comics did you read? Is this likely to be a mainstream *Superman* or have you read *Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen* or *Superman's Girl Friend, Lois Lane*?

Comment: vaguest memory of superman having damaged jimmy's brain. reminds me of the one i asked about where he poisoned his genius son to damage his brain. does he not lobotomize people in some story?

Comment: @releseabe - He's done it a few times. Mostly to neuter enemies with psychic powers

Comment: @Valorum I think by the time it came out, Jimmy and Lois's own books had been combined into Superman Family, so it could have been either that or the main books, Superman or Action. Not much help, I know!

Comment: Feels like something that would have been on Superdickery back in the day.